# axios get request for local data redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a data file with a javascript object in that I would like to store in redux state, I have an axios request function that works with an api but I want to be able to fetch a local file from my app. At the moment it doesn't display the data in redux

How can I import this into redux or is there a better way to use a local data object in redux?

**actions.js**

```
import axios from 'axios'
import {
  FETCH_DATA
} from '../../Constants'

export function fetchData() {
  return dispatch =>
    axios
      .get('../../Data/data.js')
      .then((response) => {
        dispatch({ type: FETCH_DATA, payload: response.data });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
      });
}
```

**data.js**

```
[  {
    id: 1,
    cat: ' food and drink',
    slug: 'food-and-drink',
    }, 
    {
    id: 2,
    cat: ' food and drink',
    slug: 'food-and-drink',
    }
[
```

Comment: Axios is a HTTP client and therefore not intended for pulling data from a local filesystem. You might want to load your data (which should be data.json, not data.js) in a different manner.

On the node.js side this is going to be driven by the fs module.

Answer (score 3):

```
import data from './response.json'

export function fetchData() {
  return function (dispatch) {
    dispatch({
      type: action.actionName
      payload: data
    });

  }
}
```

Comment: if you knew the answer, then why did you post the question?

Comment: I found the answer elsewhere after I posted and then added an answer to help someone else looking for the same thing

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to fetch it asynchronously.
import the data from the local file and use it in your components

```
import data from '../../Data/data.js'

render() {
return (
  {data}
)
}
```

Comment: yeah, i was just letting you know that it does not have to be done asynchronously and you can just import it. For redux too, it would be the same logic, as i see that you have already done above.